# Using Replace function in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, replace

I am try to replace the cyrlic characters by using Latin
The following codes works

```
val kztext83: String = kztext82.replace('ə','ä')
```

but the actual translation is not ä , it is a'

Since a' is two character i am getting errror for

```
val kztext83: String = kztext82.replace('ə','a'')
```

Error is  - **too many character in character literal ?**

I tried many ways including creating string , not fixing the issues

Comment: I try `"ə".replace("ə","a'")` in the kotlin REPL and it works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of replacing chars, try using Strings:

```
val kztext83: String = kztext82.replace("ə","a'")
```

Which means replacing the double quotes with single.

You can't have two chars in a single char ('a' is a char object) meaning 'a\'' is not valid.